# php array_unique with exceptions

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I want to remove duplicate values in an array except 1 value.

Eg:

```
$array = array ("apple", "orange", "orange", "banana", "grapes","grapes", "apple");
```

How can I remove all duplicate values and keep all duplicate values that equal "apple"

```
 $array = array ("apple", "orange", "banana", "grapes", "apple");
```

There are about 400 values

Comment: You want to keep the position of `apple` or simply the number of occurrences?

Answer (score 2):

```
$seen = array()
foreach ($array as $value)
    if ($value == 'apple' || !in_array($value, $seen))
        $seen[] = $value;
```

$seen will now have only the unique values, plus the apple.

Comment: And the apples? What about the apples?

Comment: clicked on update a second early, added the line right before your comment. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = array_count_values($array);
$array = array_unique($array);
$array = array_merge($array, array_fill(1, $numbers['apple'], 'apple'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array ("apple", "orange", "orange", "banana", "grapes","grapes", "apple");

$counts = array_count_values($array);

$new_array = array_fill(0, $counts['apple']-2, 'apple'); // -2 to handle there already being an apple from the array_unique count below.
$new_array = array_merge(array_unique($array), $new_array);
```